# Logstash Grok Parser not working for error logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse error logs using Logstash to capture few fields especially errormessage. But unable to capture errormessage in Logstash. Below is the actual error message and parser which I wrote

```
     12345 http://google.com 2017-04-17 09:02:43.065 ERROR 10479 --- [http-nio-8052-exec-2] com.utilities.TokenUtils     : Error

org.xml.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xe) was found in the value of attribute "ID" and element is "saml".
    at org.apache.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at com.utilities.TokenUtils.validateSignature(TokenUtils.java:99)
```

Parser:

```
`%{NOTSPACE:stnum}\s*%{NOTSPACE:requestURL}\s*%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}\s*%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s*%{NUMBER:pid}\s*---\s*\[(?<thread>[A-Za-z0-9-]+)\]\s*%{DATA:class}\s*:\s%{NOTSPACE:level}\s*(?<errormessage>.[^\n]*).[^\n]*`
```

I am trying to capture this message from the log:

```
org.xml.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xe) was found in the value of attribute "ID" and element is "saml".
```

Comment: Could you post part of your log file and the logstash filter file?

Answer (score 1):

Which logstash parser you are using? Please provide while conf file which can give us more info. Here's the sample to parse exception type from your logs (Using grok filter).

```
filter {
grok {
match => ["message", "%{DATA:errormessage} %{GREEDYDATA:EXTRA}"]
}
}
```